# Regex: match a word that's on its own, ie. not adjoined by other letters

Tags: regex

My test data:

```
<div class="row"></div> // should match
<div class="row line"></div> // should match
<div class="item row line"></div> // should match
<div class="rowBody"></div> // shouldn't match
var $itemRow = 1; // shouldn't match
```

I'm trying to replace all instances of the class `row` from a codebase.

My miserable attempts:

```
row[\W]{0}
```

and

```
row[\W]
```

Obviously neither have worked, what would I be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) are for:

```
\brow\b
```

Such an anchor matches the (zero-length) position between a character of the `\w` set and either a character of the `\W` set or a string boundary (start/end).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `\b` the `word boundary`?

```
/\brow\b/
```